# Is shim.js (phantom.js) an incurable CPU hog?

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, cpu-usage

I am writing this question in the hope that somebody else using the node.js + phantom.js stack is having, or has had the same issue.

Here it is:

I am writing a small (50 lines) node.js app for testing purposes. The app uses phantom.js that is 'required' in the code. What the app does is trivial and extremely light on resources.

The problem is that the machine I am running this in is at times under very heavy CPU load. I use this command to monitor CPU load (not real time):

```
ps -eo pcpu,pid,user,args | sort -k1 -r | head -10
```

This reveals that indeed my process ('node /srv/node/lololol/lololol.js') is never above 0.5% CPU load. Now, this is OK, but another process ('phantomjs /srv/node/phantom/node_modules/phantom/shim.js) is at all times between 98% and 99% CPU load.

So, what exactly is this 'shim.js'? Is it a resource hog? Is there a bug of phantom.js related to this? I searched around the web for some time, and found very scarce info about 'shim.js'.

Any ideas?

Comment: shim.js is the main interface (bridge) between node.js and PhantomJS on the phantom end. I guess you shouldn't ask this question because the [documentation](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node#how-does-it-work) says so: "How does it work? Don't ask. The things these eyes have seen."

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have indeed seen this, but still... Is it normal for shim.js to hog 98% of the CPU? This code does not even run constantly. It runs every 2 minutes as a cronjob.

Comment: I really don't know as I don't use PhantomJS through a bridge. I can see that it might be the case depending how the communication between node and phantom is actually implemented. Some kind of inefficient polling on the phantom end might be the culprit.